# VS Code: Rewrap block of text or comment

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I rewrap a block of text or a long comment to fit 80 columns?

I don't want it to just *render* the word wrap (this is easily achieved with Edit -> Toggle Word Wrap or setting `"editor.wordWrap": "on"`), but I want it to actually insert hard line breaks. This feature is called "fill paragraph" in some editors.

For example:

```
// This is a very long comment. I would like for this comment to occupy multiple lines rather than a single line, so that it is easy to read for other people.
```

Now I'd like to press some key to get:

```
// This is a very long comment. I would like for this comment to occupy
// multiple lines rather than a single line, so that it is easy to read for
// other people.
```

Comment: Looking for a JavaScript solution here that can run as a plugin? Does it have to be language sensitive, such as `#` vs `//`?

Comment: @tadman You can use built-in class or id to identify comments, since its all html and css.

Comment: @BladeMight Yeah, but the size of the comment delimiter impacts the wrapping, as does any indentation that might be in play. This is superficially simple but might prove to be a little obnoxious to get perfectly right. An interesting challenge.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Looks like [Rewrap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap) does what you need. Not sure if there's a native way yet. They're still adding a lot of features.

Comment: Does not respect Python doc-string preexisting indentation.

Comment: @JustinSolms I use it for python docstrings. Works great, even in item lists etc.

Answer (score 13):

[VSCodeVim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) supports this feature. Just select a block of text and press `gq`. :)

Comment: Can this be automated so that you dont have to `gq` ? Equivalent to `set textwidth` on vim ?

Comment: @umayfindurself thats probably a vscode setting somewhere

Comment: @umayfindurself Since version 1.9.1 it is possible with [Rewrap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap): `"rewrap.autoWrap.enabled": true`

Comment: I love the solution! Lean!

Comment: dang I forgot the gq command existed in vim for like a whole year until I found this answer