# How to wrap text in a VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to enable word wrap. <sup>[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31025502) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38561881)</sup>
However I only want to wrap comments. <sup>[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2524884) (VS not VS Code)</sup>
I also don't want to edit the file. <sup>[[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42912078)</sup>

I've looked through the docs, but can't find a way to change how the code is seen without changing how the code is stored.

- [`TextEditor.edit`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor.edit) allows me to change how the code is stored.
- [`DecorationRenderOptions`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DecorationRenderOptions) doesn't seem to provide a max-width option.

Is there a way implement `editor.wordWrap` in an extension?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, short of re-implementing the entire editor in a custom webview.

Comment: @Gama11 I have subsequently read all (most?) of the API in the docs and, I believe you're right. :(